# Powershell command call doesn't work when command line arguments are supplied with a variable

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to supply command line arguments to the "net accounts" command. This works when writing out the command without variables, but doesn't when passing the command line arguments with a variable.

Here's a demo script:

```
Write-Host "--- As variable"
$Sw = "/lockoutduration:15 /lockoutwindow:15"
Write-Host $Sw
&net.exe accounts $Sw
Write-Host "--- Without variable"
&net.exe accounts /lockoutduration:15 /lockoutwindow:15
```

Output:

```
> .\Test.ps1
--- As variable
/lockoutduration:15 /lockoutwindow:15
You entered an invalid value for the /LOCKOUTDURATION option.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3952.

--- Without variable
The command completed successfully.
```

What's the way to supply a set of command line arguments?

OS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2, Powershell version: 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending multiple arguments to a program you need to pass them as an array. Try:

```
Write-Host "--- As variable"
$Sw = @("/lockoutduration:15","/lockoutwindow:15")
$Sw
&net.exe accounts $Sw
```